# Ansible - registering vars

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I am working with ansible and implementing some tasks with conditional statement.
I run task1, than task2 if I get an ok from task1, and than task3 if I get an ok from task2.
I have this in my role:

```
- name: task1
  command: command1
  register: result1

- name: task2
  command: command2
  when:
    - result1.stdout is search("OK")
  register: result2

- name: task3
  command: command3
  when:
    - result2 is defined
    - result2.stdout is search("OK")
```

As you can see task2 only runs when i get OK from result1.stdout.
The problem is when task2 doesn't run I get erros in task3:

> "The conditional check '(result2.stdout is search("OK"))' failed.he error was: error while evaluating conditional (result2.stdout is search("OK")):  'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout'".

How can I change this so that i dont get this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use default filter

```
- name: task3
  command: command3
  when: result2 is defined and 
        result2.stdout | default("") is search("OK")
```

The condition is defined is not required after you use the default filter

[docs about default filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_filters.html#providing-default-values)

edit

This one will do the trick :)

```
- name: task3
  command: command3
  when: '"OK" in result2.stdout | default("")'
```